# Automated cleanup of DOM elements after Jasmine test suites run with Karma

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We have a large number of unit tests running using Jasmine suites to test a bunch of Angular/D3 applications. We noticed recently that some of the tests leave DOM elements behind after the tests are done, which build up and could potentially slow down or even influence subsequent tests - not ideal.

I know that we could be going through the test and add `afterAll()`s to cleanup after the test suites that add elements individually.

But is there potentially an automated way of removing all HTML elements from the DOM after each suite?

Test setup is using karma, jasmine and karma-chrome-launcher.

Comment: how did u add aftterALL() method

Comment: Why do you need to clean up after unit tests? If you're including DOM elements you're integration testing, not unit testing. With our integration tests we just have a function that removes all dynamically added elements and is called manually from each Jasmine spec.